# Как переделать код под вывод

Tags: c++

Как переделать код чтоб он выводил слова с нечетным количеством согласных, а не удалял их

```
void deleteWords(string str) {
    vector<string> deleteWords;
    vector<string> words = getAllWords(str);
    string keys("aeiouyAEIOUY");

    for (auto elem : words) {
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < elem.length(); i++)
            if ((int)keys.find(elem[i]) != -1) n++;
        if ((elem.length() - n) % 2 != 0)
            deleteWords.push_back(elem);
    }

    for (auto elem : deleteWords)
        str.erase(str.find(elem), elem.length());

    cout << "Result string: " << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1)`Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.` 2) Вы поймите, как этот код работает, дальше станет очевидно. 3) Вместо `(int)keys.find(elem[i]) != -1` стоит писать `keys.find(elem[i]) != std::string::npos`

Comment: @Дмитрий Зиненко,  std::string::npos это статический член и имеет значение -1, так что не там скрывается ошибка. Просто вся логика кода неправильная

Comment: @AR_Hovsepyan. 1) Логика кода правильная, просто делает не то, что нужно автору. 2) std::string в общем случае может хранить больше 2гб и приведение в int может не влезть. 3) Сишные приведения типов в с++ использовать не стоит. 4) std::string::npos не просто так ввели. Поправьте мня если я не прав, но в стандарте не сказано, что npos = -1; Да, это вряд ли кто-то будет менять, но сравнение с npos будет гарантированно работать всегда и везде. 5) Я не говорил, что конкретно тут ошибка, я сказал, что так писать не стоит из-за вышесказанных причин.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> deleteWords;
vector<string> words = getAllWords(str);
string keys("aeiouyAEIOUY");

for (auto elem : words) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elem.length(); i++)
        if ((int)keys.find(elem[i]) != -1) n++;
    if ((elem.length() - n) % 2 != 0)
        cout << "Result string: " << elem << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать  функтор, возвращающий истину, если количество согласных четное, а потом этот функтор использовать везде, где нужно

```
using std::string; 
struct Pred {
    bool operator ()(const string& s)
    {
        string keys("aeiouyAEIOUY");
        size_t count = 0;
        for (char c : s)
        {
            //если не найден среди гласных
            if (keys.find(c) == string::npos)
                ++count;
        }
        return (count & 1);
    }
};
```

А теперь функция, выводящая на консоль эти слова

```
void show_Words(string str) {   
    vector<string> words = getAllWords(str);
    cout << "Result string: ";
    std::copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, "\nResult string: "),
        Pred());
}
```